# How to update table records in sqflite database on a specific date and time in a flutter app?(Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, scheduler, sqflite

I've developed a flutter mobile application for Android. It has a 'Payment' data table. I need to update it on 31st January at 23.59 hours. How can I do this?

Invoking a function in the main class of the application is not suitable because if the app was not opened in that specific time I'm checking, the database will not be updated. So in my point of view this should be handled using an auto updating functionality.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions for this:

**First:**
If the Payment table's data is only used in your app, then you don't need to update it on the same exact time. You can just write an `if` code that runs when app open (like in splash screen) to check if the desired time (31st January at 23.59 hours) is passed. If it is passed that time, then do the things you want to do.

**Second:** You can use a [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager). This is a plugin that runs your function in background. It has a `registerOneOffTask` function for your needs.

```
void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  Workmanager.registerOneOffTask("1", "simpleTask"); //Android only (see below)
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer..But i think 1st method is not suitable because payment data is updating for every month. I just need to reset to "no data" at the end of the year to prevent mixing up with the next year data.  Running app in background is a terrible situation in performance point of view.. I'm looking for a way to schedule the task for the intended time

Comment: The app does not need to be running in the background. the workmanager works when the app is not running too. I have not used it before that's what my coworker says. And for the first solution, you can have a table named flags to store flags for each month, like (december 2021 , true) will be record in that table. The true means that december payment has been calculated. I am pretty sure you can calculated everything you need this way, unless I am not understanding your problem at all, then you can provide more detail on it.

Comment: Arash Mohammadi Thank you very much for the solution and great clarification!Thank you!